# How do I delete options and maintain a copy of the original?

Tags: jquery, dom

I have two drop downs, one which influences the other.  The first acts as a filter for the second. Hiding `(display:none)` options does not work for IE8.  So I need to actually remove the options.  But I want to be able to reset the options to the original list and filter them again for a different team.  The problem is either I delete options and never get them back OR I never delete anything.  My gut tells me it is related to references or assigning the new object back to the DOM.

1st dropdown (dd1) - the html for this is right in my code, I had difficulty displaying it.

```
<select id="pTeamFilter" onchange="teamChanged();" name="pTeamFilter">
    <option value="0">select a Team</option> 
    <option value="4"> Property Team </option> 
    <option value="7"> Rick's Team </option> 
    <option value="10"> Robert's Team </option>
</select>
```

2nd dropdown (dd2)

```
<select id="pAnalystFilter" name="pAnalystFilter">
    <option value="0">select an Analyst</option>
    <option data-teamid="7" value="682"> Clark Kent </option>
    <option data-teamid="10" value="652"> Bruce Wayne </option>
    <option data-teamid="10" value="7"> Peter Parker </option>
    <option data-teamid="13" value="971"> Bruce Banner </option>
</select>
```

**JS/jQ:**

```
var analystFullArrayElement;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    analystFullArrayElement = jQuery(document.getElementById('pAnalystFilter')).clone();
});

function teamChanged() {
    //get the team id
    var teamId = document.getElementById('pTeamFilter').value;
    //get full list of Analysts.
    var newAnalystElement = jQuery(analystFullArrayElement).clone();
    jQuery('option', newAnalystElement).each(function() {
        //remove unwanted analysts
        if ((jQuery(this).attr("data-teamid") != teamId) && (jQuery(this).val() != 0)) {
            jQuery(this).remove();
        }
    });
    document.getElementById('pAnalystFilter').innerHTML() = jQuery(newAnalystElement).html();
    //var analystElement = document.getElementById('pAnalystFilter');
    //jQuery(analystElement).val(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks to a number of the Related issues listed at the right, I now have a working solution in IE8 on XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you can:

1. Use jquery events binding instead of "onchange" attribute.
2. Use $() instead of jQuery. If you use noConflict, you can do this

   (function ($) {
       your code here with $ instead jQuery
   })(jQuery);
3. Use `$(function () {})` instead of `$(document).ready(function () {})`
4. Use chaining. I mean

   jQuery('#pAnalystFilter').empty().append(jQuery(newAnalystElement).html());
5. Use data() method to get attr('data-smth')
6. If you use $(this) more than one time, it's better to store it in a variable

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {

        var analystFullArrayElement; // by the way, your global scope is clean and it is good

        $(function() {
            analystFullArrayElement = $('#pAnalystFilter').clone();
        });

        $("#pTeamFilter").change(function () {
            //get the team id
            var teamId = $('#pTeamFilter').val();
            //get full list of Analysts.
            var newAnalystElement = $(analystFullArrayElement).clone();
            $('option', newAnalystElement).each(function(){
                //remove unwanted analysts
                var $this = $(this);
                if(($this.data("teamid") != teamId) && ($this.val() != 0)){
                    $this.remove();
                }
            });                
            $('#pAnalystFilter').empty().append($(newAnalystElement).html());
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Also yoг can avoid comparison `($this.val() != 0)` by adding :gt(0) in selector and than apply filter, so

```
$('option', newAnalystElement).each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(($this.data("teamid") != teamId) && ($this.val() != 0)){
        $this.remove();
    }
});
```

turns into

```
$('option:gt(0)', newAnalystElement).filter(function () {
    return $(this).data("teamid") != teamId;
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Two changes.
1. I changed the document.getElements to jQuery calls.

```
            analystFullArrayElement = jQuery('#pAnalystFilter').clone();
```

1. I used a .empty() followed by a .append() to get rid of the old list and apply the new list.

   ```
       function teamChanged(){
           //get the team id
           var teamId = jQuery('#pTeamFilter').val();
           //get full list of Analysts.
           var newAnalystElement = jQuery(analystFullArrayElement).clone();
           alert(jQuery(newAnalystElement).html());
           jQuery('option', newAnalystElement).each(function(){
               //remove unwanted analysts
               if((jQuery(this).attr("data-teamid") != teamId) && (jQuery(this).val() != 0)){
                   jQuery(this).remove();
               }
           });
           alert(jQuery(newAnalystElement).html());                
           jQuery('#pAnalystFilter').empty();
           jQuery('#pAnalystFilter').append(jQuery(newAnalystElement).html());
       }
   ```